# Присваивание функции всплывающей кнопки

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Подскажите, нашёл в Интернете [вот такую инструкцию](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-uialertview-and-uialertviewdelegate--mobile-3159), как сделать всплывающие кнопки. Сделал - всё заработало, но идея заключается в том, чтобы при нажатии на всплывающую кнопку происходил звонок. Как это сделать?

Я делаю так: в .h файл вставляю

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *call;
```

а в .m файле должна быть строка

```
        - (IBAction)call24:(id)sender {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:81111111111"]];
    }
```

И вот вопрос: как мне вставить в функцию

```
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 2"])
{
    NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");
}
```

вместо того, чтобы при нажатии кнопки просто значение отражалось в логах, происходил звонок?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Если вы хотите вызвать - `(IBAction)call24:(id)sender`, то это можно сделать, например, так `[self call24:nil]`.

Comment: @Zatoichy Да, я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на Button 2 происходил звонок.
Т.е. мне нужно вставить код - `(IBAction)call24....`, а вместо `NSLog(@....` вставить `[self call24:nil]`, так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Гошка Тарасов](/users/16329/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/16329/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) В таком случае, можете, сразу вместо NSLog вставить `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:81111111111"]];`

ПС. Уж извините, но ваш вопрос некорректен, так же как заголовок.

Comment: спасибо, заработало

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов если заработало, отметьте ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Так:

```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

    -(IBAction)buttonPress:(UIButton*)sender{
         if([sender isEqual:button1]){
             //Обработать действие для 1-й кнопки
         } else if([sender isEqual:button2]){
             //Обработать действие для 2-й кнопки
         }
    }
```

Или так, предварительно выставив нужные теги для кнопок:

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Buttons){
    Button1,
    Button2,
 };

 -(IBAction)buttonPress:(UIButton*)sender{
         switch (sender.tag) {
        case Button1:
            //Обработать действие для 1-й кнопки
            break;
        case Button2:
            //Обработать действие для 2-й кнопки
            break;
    }
 }
```